# Fails to call methods of deployed contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura, rinkeby

Contract deployed to [Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x97CBBa2EBC8Be957c0a78e93230021E4d4b7Ab90)

---

**Contract code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

contract Cont {

  address[] players;
  uint test = 123;

function enter() public payable { // send() from web3 sucsseded
    require(msg.value > .01 ether, "Sender don't have enogth ether");
    players.push(msg.sender);
  }

function getTest() public view returns (uint) { // call() from Web3 fails
    return test;
  }
}
```

**Contract execution Script code**

executed from `node`

`web3 JS` - v1.4.0

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const ADDRESS = '0x97CBBa2EBC8Be957c0a78e93230021E4d4b7Ab90'
const ABI = [
{
  inputs: [],
  name: 'enter',
  outputs: [],
  stateMutability: 'payable',
  type: 'function',
  constant: undefined,
  payable: true,
  signature: '0xe97dcb62'
},
{
  inputs: [],
  name: 'getTest',
  outputs: [Array],
  stateMutability: 'view',
  type: 'function',
  constant: true,
  payable: undefined,
  signature: '0xa8cd0a80'
}
]


const web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/640cae69b9ac44c4bb7090bd71dc2ec3")
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS) 

contract.methods.getTest().call().then(
   (res) => {console.log(res); // (node:9358) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
});
```

NOTE: The send() method works. Tested on [another](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x6b6e9969161ad6418d339ca54b12955447ef2ce7) contract.

Comment: Hi, I believe it's something wrong with your ABI or the contract method. Can you please share your contract code?

Comment: Hey @MiroslavNedelchev,
Included the contract also one note the send() method works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning uint on your contract but your abi says it is array I'm not sure but you should check your abi. I couldn't add comment because of reputation.

Comment: Thanks for mention. I was using my [compile](https://probable-poultry-ddd.notion.site/Compile-solidity-contracts-e1b3fb8fcde24a189e8d524b9b838d63), [deploy](https://probable-poultry-ddd.notion.site/Deploy-Smart-Contract-ccb078f2fa684d34b45eeaaf5046ec9b) scripts the issue could be there. 

Recently discover truffle let me try to use it.

Comment: You were right, the issue was in the ABI. Used the `truffle` to compile and deploy contracts the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in the custom compile script / ABI. Used the [truffle lib](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs) to compile and deploy the contract. The issue was gone.